# selecting specific ordered lists

Tags: jquery, css

I have a wikipedia API returning html with multiple non-classed ol's. eg.

```
<div id = "wikiInfo">
  <ol></ol>
  <p></p>
  <ol></ol>
  <p></p>
  <ol></ol>

</div>
```

So I want to single out only the first two and extract the text.

I have managed to select only the ol's but for some reason I can's get n'th child working with ol's

```
$('#wikiInfo').find("div ol:nth-child(-n+2)").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#wikiInfo').children("ol:lt(2)").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nXuC6/)

Comment: documentation: [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (categories allow to see the other selectors like :gt, :last, etc)

Comment: @Arun P Johny. Is there any way to select only the ol's that are direct children on #wikiInfo? Because I am currently getting Ol's within other elements lighting.

Comment: @rolandnsharp see the update... use `children` instead of `find`